# Framework to create a tutorial for a webapp?

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring, web-applications

We have a webapp (built in Java & Spring if that matters), and I want to create tutorials for the site, so the first time someone enters a section, it gives them a walkthrough of that section (waiting for them to click on appropriate buttons etc).

Are there are frontend/backend frameworks that help with building tutorials on top of your software?  I know we could build our own using state information and javascript, but I was wondering if there are any already existing toolkits that would make this process much easier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use something like this tool https://github.com/usablica/intro.js

It's easy to integrate this one to any webpage.

Comment: That looks promising @michael-kachanovskyy - I'll check it out.